# understand the performance diff of std::optional on different platforms

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, option-type

I was trying to understand the overhead of using `std::optional` in the interface design, whether it's worthing using `std::optional` for single interface or using combination of "isNull and getX", the main concern is to understand the overhead of `std::optional`. So I crafted this simple program to test it out.

The code snippet and test results are summarized in this gist https://gist.github.com/shawncao/fa801d300c4a0a2826240fd9f5961db2

Surprisingly, there are two things I don't understand, I would like to hear from experts to help

- on the linux platform with gcc (8 and 9 both tested), I saw consistently `std::optional` is better than the direct condition, this is something I don't understand.
- on Mac (my laptop), I saw the program executes way faster than the time measured on linux (12ms vs >60ms), I don't see why this is the case (is it because of Apple LLVM impl?), from the CPU info, I don't think the mac is faster, maybe I missed other information to check.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Basically understand the runtime difference between these two platforms, maybe processors related, or compiler related, I'm not sure. Repro app is attached in the gist. Also, I don't quite understand why `std::optional` is faster on linux with GCC.

https://gist.github.com/shawncao/fa801d300c4a0a2826240fd9f5961db2

see details in the gist.

Code Snippet (copied from the gist based on suggestion)

```
inline bool f1ni(int i) {
  return i % 2 == 0;
}

TEST(OptionalTest, TestOptionalPerf) {
  auto f1 = [](int i) -> int {
    return i + 1;
  };

  auto f2 = [](int i) -> std::optional<int> {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      return {};
    }
    return i + 1;
  };

  // run 1M cycles
  constexpr auto cycles = 100000000;
  nebula::common::Evidence::Duration duration;
  long sum2 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < cycles; ++i) {
    auto x = f2(i);
    if (x) {
      sum2 += x.value();
    }
  }
  LOG(INFO) << fmt::format("optional approach: sum={0}, time={1}", sum2, duration.elapsedMs());

  duration.reset();
  long sum1 = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < cycles; ++i) {
    if (i % 2 != 0) {
      sum1 += f1(i);
    }
  }
  LOG(INFO) << fmt::format("special value approach: sum={0}, time={1}", sum1, duration.elapsedMs());
  EXPECT_EQ(sum1, sum2);
```

---

Laptop Mac MacOs Mojave 
Processor 2.6 GHz Intel Core i7
/usr/bin/g++ --version

> Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
>   Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
>   Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
>   Thread model: posix
>   InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

```
[Test Output]
I0812 09:36:20.678683 348009920 TestCommon.cpp:354] optional approach: sum=2500000050000000, time=13
I0812 09:36:20.692001 348009920 TestCommon.cpp:363] special value approach: sum=2500000050000000, time=12
```

Linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
36 cores - one of them
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 85
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8124M CPU @ 3.00GHz
stepping        : 4
microcode       : 0x100014a
cpu MHz         : 1685.329
cache size      : 25344 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 36
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 18
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 13
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rtm mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke

/usr/bin/g++ --version

> g++ (Ubuntu 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~18.04) 9.1.0
>   Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

```
[Test Output]
I0812 16:42:07.391607 15080 TestCommon.cpp:354] optional approach: sum=2500000050000000, time=59
I0812 16:42:07.473335 15080 TestCommon.cpp:363] special value approach: sum=2500000050000000, time=81
```

===== build flags =====
**[build commands capture for Mac]**

/usr/bin/g++ -I/Users/shawncao/nebula/include -I/Users/shawncao/nebula/src -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.70.0/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/folly/2019.08.05.00/include -I/Users/shawncao/nebula/build/cuckoofilter/src/cuckoofilter/src -I/Users/shawncao/nebula/build/fmtproj-prefix/src/fmtproj/include -I/Users/shawncao/nebula/src/service/gen/nebula -isystem /usr/local/include -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/gflagsp-prefix/src/gflagsp-build/include -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/glogp-prefix/src/glogp-build -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/roaringproj-prefix/src/roaringproj/include -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/roaringproj-prefix/src/roaringproj/cpp -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/yomm2-prefix/src/yomm2/include -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/xxhash-prefix/src/xxhash -isystem /Users/shawncao/nebula/build/bloom/src/bloom -isystem /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/include -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-error=nullability-completeness -Wno-error=sign-compare -Wno-error=unknown-warning-option -O3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -std=gnu++1z -o CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/src/common/test/TestExts.cpp.o -c /Users/shawncao/nebula/src/common/test/TestExts.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable CommonTests
/Applications/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-error=nullability-completeness -Wno-error=sign-compare -Wno-error=unknown-warning-option -O3 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/src/common/test/TestCommon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/src/common/test/TestExts.cpp.o -o CommonTests -Wl,-rpath,/Users/shawncao/nebula/build/bloom/src/bloom-build/lib libNCommon.a yomm2-prefix/src/yomm2-build/src/libyomm2.a googletest-prefix/src/googletest-build/lib/libgtest.a googletest-prefix/src/googletest-build/lib/libgtest_main.a xxhash-prefix/src/xxhash/libxxhash.a roaringproj-prefix/src/roaringproj-build/src/libroaring.a glogp-prefix/src/glogp-build/libglog.a gflagsp-prefix/src/gflagsp-build/lib/libgflags.a bloom/src/bloom-build/lib/libbf.dylib libcflib.a /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2s/lib/libssl.a fmtproj-prefix/src/fmtproj-build/libfmt.a

**[build commands capture for Linux]**
/usr/bin/g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -lstdc++ -Wl,--no-as-needed -no-pie -ldl -lunwind -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -O3 -s CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/src/common/test/TestCommon.cpp.o CMakeFiles/CommonTests.dir/src/common/test/TestExts.cpp.o -o CommonTests -Wl,-rpath,/home/shawncao/nebula/build/bloom/src/bloom-build/lib libNCommon.a yomm2-prefix/src/yomm2-build/src/libyomm2.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest.a /usr/local/lib/libgtest_main.a xxhash-prefix/src/xxhash/libxxhash.a roaringproj-prefix/src/roaringproj-build/src/libroaring.a /usr/local/lib/libglog.a /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a bloom/src/bloom-build/lib/libbf.so libcflib.a /usr/local/lib/libssl.a /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.a fmtproj-prefix/src/fmtproj-build/libfmt.a -lpthread

Comment: Are you compiling the code with optimizations enabled? If not, any performance measurement/comparison is pointless.

Comment: @Jesper all build using release build type with "-O3", these results are with the same optimization settings as far as I can tell.

Comment: All of the code is inline? In surprised part of is ain't completely gone en replaced by the result. I don't find your results logical. However, assuming the typo in f1, I don't know if the 2 do the same

Comment: You are calling f1, but showing f1ni. Can you please show the relevant code (f1)
!?

Comment: What's the timing if you put the `f1` code first and then the `f2` code? Or if you test them separately (only one loop at a time)? Maybe the compiler is smart enough to see that both loops are equal and just generates code for `sum1=sum2` (OK, doesn't really like so, we should have fewer cycles then)? Can you first stop the timing and then call the logging function (I don't know how much work `LOG(INFO)` is doing.

Comment: @JVApen, sorry I missed f1 function in my paste, updated the code snippet.

Comment: [quick-bench's result](http://quick-bench.com/N1Ep9VIQaEc86l9M0Bn7f7VzqEw) shows same things.

Comment: Different code, same remark: `i*i` and `i+1` ain't the same thing

Comment: @ShawnCao The data that you provide looks inconsistent. `f1` and `f2` are different, but the logs show that the results from both loops are equal. How can that be?
.

Comment: @WernerHenze,  I tried re-order, it won't change the test result as show in the post.

Comment: @Jarod42: important difference: `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);`

Comment: @JVApen, my bad again, I was trying different thing to see if compiler (on mac) to stop optimizations. The test results were based on "i+1" for both, I have corrected the post with updates.

Comment: @WernerHenze, as I replied to JVApen, it's messed up with copy / paste, sorry about that, I have corrected the post. They should be based on the same logic, otherwise, test results won't match.

Comment: @Jarod42, quick-bench is wonderful, I'll play more with it, thanks for sharing. 
But it doesn't solve my puzzles (about why 1) mac version is so much faster 2) std::optional is faster which against my intuition)

Comment: @JVApen: Did I miss something? my both code use `benchmark::DoNotOptimize(sum);` and the only difference should be optional versus regular code.

Comment: Comparing code from different OS is hard to compare, as other factor might interfere. Not sure how compiler better optimize code with optional.

Comment: @jarod42 Your code does, the question does not

Comment: There might be some relation to vectorization. I tried to transform the code into a form where the addition is unconditional: http://quick-bench.com/NoTt-HQigkFlPFA5z_4-d70ekuU. Then, GCC vectorized it and this version was the fastest one on Quick Benchmark. Also, all the versions were much faster with Clang: http://quick-bench.com/KwxAyp2Kt1Qs_2lCQw-6_HyGHX4, which was able to recognize the _mod 2_ pattern and avoid the no-op branches completely.

Comment: The results vary a lot with the version of the compiler and the exact flags. clang does great by doing i+=2 and skipping the branch, but adding -ffast-math or -march=native (skylake) slows it down by a huge factor. gcc, with -O3 -march=native, can get a nice boost from vectorization, although it doesn't seem to be done optimally. Anyway, the abstraction of std::optional does disappear, the loop just looks very slightly different, which can have random effects with the optimization heuristics...